# Do systemd --user services shutdown properly?

Tags: systemd, shutdown

I have a few services that I launch with systemd when I login in my user account, e.g. I did:

```
systemctl --user enable foo.service
```

But I usually terminate my X session abruptly, i.e. just pressing the power button to directly initiate systemd shutdown (I have a minimal desktop environment). Systemd terminates X sending all the child processes to the grave.

Will systemd gracefully shutdown the `--user` foo service in this case?

Answer (score 5):

`systemd --user` runs as a system service called `user@.service`.  This is a template service.  Your instance might be `user@1000.service`.  The number is your user ID (`id -u`).

The system shutdown procedure will signal `user@1000.service` to stop, with the usual signal `SIGTERM`.  In response, the `systemd --user` process will signal each user service to stop.[*]

`systemctl cat user@.service` suggests there is little point setting a user service timeout (grace period) any longer than 120 seconds.  After that, all the user services will recieve `SIGKILL` from the main system (PID 1).  `SIGKILL` is immediately fatal.

To understand the settings in this file, see `man systemd.kill`, and also `man systemd.service`.

---

[*] Technically, what `systemd --user` does in response to `SIGTERM` is to  activate the user unit `exit.target`.   This is mentioned in `man systemd`.  For more information about `exit.target`: `systemctl cat exit.target` will tell you to look in `man systemd.special` :-).

Comment: I don't have a desktop environment like GNOME or KDE, when pressing the power button my system launches `systemctl shutdown` which terminates X and all the child processes and I was wondering if it would terminate also the systemd user services in a bad way. Based on your answer I guess it does not. I have edited my question to clarify this point.

Comment: @FedericoSquartini hum. Technically, X clients don't *have* to die when they lose their connection to the server. But often, they don't have much better to do. systemd user services can potentially be X clients, but that doesn't mean they can't clean up carefully if X is just killed.  Some of this can depend on how well the service program is written though - there are definitely some examples of "bad" programs over the years.

Comment: My services are just servers, they do not depend on X. I guess the point is whether they are in the X process tree, login shell process tree, or not. I just printed the process tree, and it seems they are not, so everything should be fine and even after X has terminated the user services should still be alive until systemd stops them (likely immediately after).

Comment: @FedericoSquartini technically processes can be moved between systemd units.  I mention this to say that `systemctl status` can show a tree of processes and which systemd unit they are in.  (I.e. you don't have to pass a service name to `systemctl status`.  If you don't pass a service name, it should show the full tree of all processes on the system).